# Warning in C++: Pointer holds a value that must be examined when trying to assign new int32_t

Tags: c++, pointers, warnings, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

I was trying to learn dynamic memory allocation in C++.
My program compiles and works, but Visual Studio throws these warnings at me.

What do they mean?

```
Warning C28193  'ptr' holds a value that must be examined.
Warning C28182  Dereferencing NULL pointer. 'ptr' contains the same NULL value as 
'new(1*4, nothrow)'
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int* ptr = nullptr;

    if (!ptr) {
        ptr = new (std::nothrow) int32_t;
        *ptr = 10;
    }

    std::cout << *ptr << "\n";

}
```

Comment: What's your compiler options? Not getting a warning on gcc, clang or msvc with standard settings.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner to this, so it's whatever standard VS settings are. The only difference is I'm using C++20.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
new (std::nothrow) int32_t
```

Attempts to allocate the memory for `int32_t`, and if it cannot, it doesn't throw an exception, it returns `nullptr`.

You go ahead and assign a number (10) to it, but you need to first determine if the memory allocation succeeded by checking if `ptr` is nullptr or not before assigning the value. It's trying to tell you that you need some error checking.

Same thing when you print it out, it may be a nullptr and you need to examine that.

Comment: So I should add an ```if``` which checks if it's ```NULL``` and only prints if it isn't, right?

Comment: @AbhinavJha I would just `exit()`. If a memory allocation fails there is not much you can do but close your application.

Comment: @AbhinavJha Yes, something like `if (ptr == nullptr) exit();` or some other kind of panic.

Comment: In that case I just wouldn't use `std::nothrow` in the first place? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Salvage Really not the best use-case here, it would be better off when trying to allocate large buffers. I'd be surprised if the program could run in the first place if you couldn't allocate 4 bytes.

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd use `std::nothrow` over just catching `std::bad_alloc`?

Comment: @Salvage some environments don't have exceptions.

Comment: I am learning C++ from learncpp.com, and I simply haven't studied exception handling yet